# Klingon unit of distance in space

Tags: star-trek, klingon, klingon-language

In *The Search for Spock* and *The Final Frontier*, the respective bridge officers of Captain Kruge and Captain Klaa's ships use "kellikams" (perhaps "kellicams") as a unit of distance in space.  An example usage might be:

> ***20,000 kellikams and closing!***

The unit may have also been used in some episodes of the *TNG*-era series (perhaps the *DS9* episode "[Once More unto the Breach](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Once_More_Unto_the_Breach_(episode))", before, during, or after the raid on Trelka V's Dominion outpost).

**Can anyone provide a reference for converting 1 kellikam to a Terran unit?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently the spelling is "kellicam", and the [Memory Alpha wiki article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kellicam) says:

> Klingon transporter systems have a range of 20,000 kellicams. (TNG:
>   "Redemption") ... It was stated in "A Matter Of Honor" that Federation
>   transporters have a range of 40,000 kilometers. If Klingon
>   transporters have a similar range, this would indicate that 1 kellicam
>   is approximately equal to 2 kilometers. This is the measurement given
>   by the *Star Trek Encyclopedia*.

The [*Star Trek Encyclopedia*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671536095) was co-written by TNG-era technical consultant [Michael Okuda](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Michael_Okuda), so this is probably about as close to canon as you can get without an actual onscreen conversion. Note that the entry (which you can see on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT1099)) says that the conversion is approximate:

> Kellicam : Unit of distance measure in use by the Klingon Empire. One
>   kellicam seemed *roughly* equal to two kilometers.

Comment: 40000 km?  They have to enter the Stratosphere to beam people to the ground on Earth?

Comment: @Taemyr ~40000km is Earth circumference ;) [Stratosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratosphere) is at ~40km (40000m)

Comment: @Taemyr: They can comfortably beam down from a [geostationary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit). ;-)

Comment: @Taemyr I believe this diagram might be useful [Diagram](http://www.theozonehole.com/images/atmosnasa.jpg)

Comment: The stratosphere ends at approximately 50 km, or 0.125 % of the purported range of a Federation transporter.